# Discord.js add specific roles to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am working on a Discord bot that assigns roles to users. If the pinged user and the user who has executed the command has a specific role, I want to add this to a const.

```js
const role1 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "role1")
const role2 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "role2")
const role3 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "role3")
const roles = [ role1, role2, role3 ]
        
let pingedUser = message.mentions.members.first();
        
const userRole = roles.filter(role => pingedUser.roles.cache.has(role.id))
const ownRole = roles.filter(role => message.member.roles.cache.has(role.id));

console.log(userRole);
console.log(ownRole);
```

I get this error in the console: "Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined"

I would be very happy if someone has a solution in mind :)

Edit:
This is how I am executing the command (index.js):

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'testcommand') {
        client.commands.get('testcommand').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
    } 
});
```

And this is my whole command-file (commands/testcommand.js):

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'testcommand',
    description: "",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {    
        const role1 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "role1")
        const role2 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "role2")
        const role3 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "role3")
        const roles = [ role1, role2, role3 ]
        
        let pingedUser = message.mentions.members.first();

        if (!pingedUser) {
            return
          }

        const userRole = roles.filter(role => pingedUser.roles.cache.has(role.id))
        const ownRole = roles.filter(role => message.member.roles.cache.has(role.id));

        console.log(userRole);
        console.log(ownRole);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`GuildMemberRoleManager#cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache) returns a `Collection<Snowflake, Role>` where [`Snowflake`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake) (`id`) is the key and [`Role`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role) is the value. So, you should be checking if the collection has the `role.id` key. And you can simplify your code using [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Make sure `pingedUser` exists before computing their roles.

```js
if (!pingedUser) {
  return message.reply('User mention missing')
}

const roles = [role1, role2, role3]
const userRoles = roles.filter(role => pingedUser.roles.cache.has(role.id))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed the code a little bit and added your suggestion, but now I am getting an error in the console. I updated the post. Would be glad if you could help :)

Comment: @DavidB Looks like the message didn't have any user mentions. You can check if `pingedUser` exists before computing their roles.

Comment: this line: "const userRole = roles.filter(role => pingedUser.roles.cache.has(role.id))"

Comment: @DavidB You don't have to remove your actual question when making edits. You can add an **Edit** section and add your follow-up questions.

Comment: Now its just returning every time, without giving me an console-output (console.log) :/

Comment: @DavidB Well, I was asking for the message you're using to test the command. If the message has a user mention, the code should log the user's roles and the message author's roles. You could use `message.reply('User mention missing')` when there are no message mentions.

Comment: @DavidB Weird, that should work.  Can you try adding `console.log(message.content, message.mentions.members)` before the `if` condition?

Comment: It says "Collection(0) [Map] {}"

Comment: @DavidB [MessageMentions#members only returns the mentioned members in text channels](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members). Looks like you're not testing the bot in one. Are you testing in a [`DMChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel)?

Comment: So, what do I have to change?

Comment: @DavidB You don't have to change the code. Test the bot in a text channel.

Comment: Still getting "Collection(0) [Map] {}" when pinging another user :(